# Building file service with using Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, file, download

I'm trying to build a file service, I'm planning to run this service on my file server, and this service stores and retrieves files from file system of the server, i mean outside from the application's own context . I want to ask my questions over the code;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/public/")
public class FileDownloadTestController {

@GetMapping("{parentDir}/{childDir}/{fileName}")
public void getSomeFile(@PathVariable("parentDir") String parentDirectory,
                        @PathVariable("childDir") String childDirectory,
                        @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,
                        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String fullPath = getFullPath(parentDirectory, childDirectory, fileName);

    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try (InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fullPath)) {

        MediaType mediaType = getMediaType(servletContext, fileName);
        response.setContentType(mediaType.getType());

        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=" + fileName);

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[128];
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

This peace of code works well but;

1) What I basically aim to do, is to access the source (meaning a file) with a url similar to the example below;

> http://file.somedomain.com/abc/def/ghi.jpg

Is this the right way to do this? (I ask this because I wonder if you can suggest another approach)

2) If my approach is the right way, then is this secure to be used? Is it possible for a user to send a malicious request, if so how do i handle it, and avoid such requests beforehand?

3) Is it right to allow the service to directly access the server's file system?

Comment: Maybe you should split this question into 3 single questions. Each question should be descibed simple. And the title of each question should be the question, ends with a "?". I think then there is more chance for answers.

Comment: I wonder if an attacker might be able to get your production jar/war file using this?